# Suggestions to manage different contents for a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, custom-controls, uitableview

In my application I present a `UITableViewController` with custom `UITableViewCell`s. Each cell has been created throught .xib file. I decided to take this way because each cell displays different elements. Elements are a `UILabel`, a `UITextField` and a `UIImageView`. Each cell displays info about products.

The code I use to present the custom cell is the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];     
        cell = self.customTableViewCellOutlet;

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.backgroundView = [[[BackgroundCell alloc] init] autorelease];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[[BackgroundCell alloc] init] autorelease];
    }

    // configure the cell with data
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];    

    return cell;
}
```

where `self.customTableViewCellOutlet` is an outlet to the cell .xib file with an assign retain policy.

The code works very well.

Now I need to implement the following two specifictions:

**1)** First, when the user taps in a `UITextField`, that element becomes editable. When the user taps outside  the modified value is saved and the `UITextField` becomes not editable.

For this first specification I thought about the following mechanism. The File's owner for my .xib file could be `UITableViewController`. Doing this, my `UITableViewController` could implement `UITextFieldDelegate` and listen for `UITextField` events. The only aspect that is not clear for me is how to listen when the user taps outside the `UITextField`.

**2)** When the user tap in a row, the cell has to change its content. In particular, each cell has to change its content. From displaying a product (good) to presenting a detailed description for that product. In other words, when the user tap the cell I need tho swicth from a view (that one that displays raws info) to another one.

Here I don't know how to proceed.

Could you provide me some suggestions? Thank in you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

implementing the textField Delegate in UITableViewController or UITableViewCell depends on the requirements.
wether u wanted the written text to be in array? then u can set index as tag of textField. Then get the text in delegate and add to the array then reload the table.
Another thing u can add a tap gesture on the cell, which returns u the row, when tapped outside the textField..